# Increase Azure Translate limit to more than 10000 chars per call

Tags: language-translation, microsoft-translator

I want to increase the 10,000 chars limit for text translation in Azure, either with standard subscription or custom subscription, but I cant find how. If it’s not possible please suggest any workarounds.

Currently I making multiple calls in order to make sure limit is not exceeded, but that becomes complex and takes more time and I'm looking for a more efficient method

Comment: I rephrazed it a bit to make it more like SO guidelines, though the replacement request is not allowed here (as thats an opinion). Didnt close vote for the first half of th question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the limit for Azure Translator is 10,000 characters per request and this cannot be exceeded as per the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/request-limits)

You could possibly break down your source texts into chunks of 10,000 characters and then send them in parallel to Azure Translator. How you do this depends on the programming language you're working in. For example, you would do something like this in Go.

Firstly, chunk your source text into batches of 10,000 characters each as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514256/1893998)

Then, translate each of the chunks in parallel with something like this. Note that `callMicrosoftTranslation` is a stub here for the code which would actually call the Azure Translator API.

```golang
microsoftTranslationResponses := make(map[string]*microsoft.TranslationResponse)
g, _ := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)
for chunkKey, chunkValue := range chunkMap {
    // bind to each iteration to work with closures
    // https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines
    chunkKey := chunkKey
    chunkValue := chunkValue

    g.Go(func() error {
        translationResponse, err := callMicrosoftTranslation(chunkValue)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        mutex.Lock()
        microsoftTranslationResponses[chunkKey] = translationEngineResponse
        mutex.Unlock()

        return nil
    })
}
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```